# unable to set tableview background & label background as same color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UILabel` above the table view.I want to set the background color of label same as `UITableView`.

i have set the `UILabel` background color as below.

```
 self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.2];
```

i have set the table view background color as below.

```
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.2];
```

but i am getting both the diffrent colors?Please tell me why?

Comment: It's happening because of alpha. Behind `UILabel` and `UITableView` there may be different views with different colour and it make their effect while you set colour.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your contentView's backgroundColor of tableviewCell is not set to clearColor:

```
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: still there is little difference.Table view color is little blurry but label background is compltete clear

Comment: I don't get it,When you use UIColor which's alpha is lower than 1.0,  you can see through it.So what you see was different if what underneath of them were different.

Comment: instead of cell.contentview.backgroundColor try cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];